# Jruby on Rails Development Box on Mac Mini (Snow Leopard or Lion OS)

Tags: glassfish, jruby, jrubyonrails, torquebox

This weekend, I'm planning to attempt to configure my new Mac Mini as a Jruby development box.  I have been doing some research on the subject and there seem to be a variety of ways to go.   I was hoping some of you have been been down this road recently and could offer suggestions on the best configuration, pit falls to avoid or general guidance.

I've read about Torque Box, Glass Fish and others and frankly don't know which way to turn.

Any input would be appreciated.

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say keep it simple to start.  You don't need TorqueBox or Glassfish just yet (although you may choose to deploy on one of these).

For now, just download and install JRuby, then `jruby -S gem install rails` and away you go!